# Adding item into inventory using a unique ID (python)

Tags: python

I am attempting to write an RPG game and am stuck on how to call items, monsters, quests, etc. using a single unique ID to get all the data. This is essentially based on the top answer in [this Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57438/game-inventory-system).

Rather than passing all data to the `Item` class, I'd like to call a method or function that has a dictionary of all the items which then passes the data to `Item` based on a single unique ID.

The relevant code I currently have is the following (all code can be found [here](https://github.com/phobos101/Master-of-Avalon/blob/master/game.py)):

```
inventory.add_item(Item(ListItem.list(1))) #The 1 is a placeholder to specifically get the sword.

class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = {}

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.items[item.name] = item

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, attack, armor, cost, quantity, description):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.armor = armor
        self.cost = cost
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.description = description


class ListItem(object):
# This is a database to hold all the games loot/items
    def __init__(self):
    # What goes here? 

    def list(self, itemid):
    # Probably don't even need this here? Can it go under __init__?
        all_items = {
            1: {"name": "Sword", "desc": "A rusty looking sword", "dmg": 5,         "arm": 1, "val": 10},

            }
        return list(all_items[itemid].values())
```

Comment: You seem to be treating `ListItem.list` as a **class method**, so you don't necessarily need *anything* in `ListItem.__init__`. However, it's not really clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why is `ListItem()` a class in the first place?  Unless I'm reading it wrong, it's meant strictly to be an **action**, in which case a class is probably not appropriate for it.  It seems to me that `list` would be more appropriate as a method of `Inventory`, FWIW.

Comment: Thanks for the answers thus far. I am new to programming so trying to understand these concepts. To clarify what I am trying to achieve:

Rather than when a player picks up an item and calling inventory.add_item(Item('sword', 10, 1, 10, 1, 'A rusty looking sword'))

I'd like to to 'inventory.add_item(Item(unique ID here that references all the data which will pass that data to Item class.))

Answer (score 0):

I got it working but perhaps not the most efficient way as follows:

1) Removed the ListItem class

2) Added the dictionary to the main method

3) set a variable iid (item ID) to be whatever the value is of the item in the room

4) Passed each value of the item to the Item class

This does however limit me to one item per location.

```
location = {
    2: {"name": "Cave - Upper area",
        "description": "Placeholder",
        "west": 1,
        "south": 4,
        "item": "sword",
        "iid": 1},

all_items = {
    1: {"name": "Sword", "dmg": 5, "arm": 1, "val": 10, "desc": "A rusty looking sword"},
    100: {"name": "Beer", "desc": "A foaming mug of ale", "dmg": 1, "arm": 1, "val": 1}
    }

elif move[0] == "get":
    if "iid" in location[currentLocation] and move[1] in location[currentLocation]["item"]:
        iid = location[currentLocation]["iid"]
        inventory.add_item(Item(all_items[iid]["name"], all_items[iid]["dmg"], all_items[iid]["arm"], all_items[iid]["val"], all_items[iid]["desc"]))
        print("%s added to inventory!\n" % all_items[iid]["name"])
        del location[currentLocation]["item"]
    else:
        print("\nThere is no %s here!\n" % move[1])
```